# Is it possible to get from Johannesburg to Cathedral Peak in 1 day using public transport?

Tags: public-transport, south-africa, hitchhiking

I want to go from

1. Johannesburg to Harrismith using Greyhound or similar bus company (leaving early in the morning and arriving midday),
2. From Harrismith to Bergville using a minibus-taxi,
3. And finally from Bergville to Cathedral Peak using a minibus-taxi / hitch-hiking arriving before the Cathedral Peak office closes (at 19h00).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 5):

From Bergville, you probably have to rely on the kindness of strangers, but from Johannesburg to Bergville should not be a problem.

One option is to take [the Joburg to Durban train](https://www.shosholozameyl.co.za/train-routes.html) and get off in Ladysmith (at 2:45am). Another is to take the 8:15am [Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.co.za) to Harrismith, which is scheduled to arrive at 11:25am. That should be early enough to get you to Bergville, but I don't know where the combis leave from in Harrismith.